# how to suppress foreach() warnings php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, for-loop, foreach

I need help suppressing a warning that I am getting from a `foreach()`

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
/sitename/pages/admin/questions/index.php
```

I am getting the result I want. All I need is to remove the warning...

This is my code:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $RESULTS_count; $i++){

$rawResult = $wpdb->get_row(
                $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".WPSQT_TABLE_RESULTS." WHERE id = $i"),ARRAY_A);

$rawResult['sections'] = unserialize($rawResult['sections']);

     foreach($rawResult['sections'] as $result_sections){
         if($result_sections['answers'][1]['mark'] == 'correct') $correct_answer++;
    }
}
echo $correct_answer/$RESULTS_count;
```

If I take the code out of the FOR loop and replace `WHERE id = $i` with `WHERE id = 1` it will work... Could the problem be FOREACH does not like being in FOR loop?

What do you think I should do?

EDIT: I think the warning I was getting was caused by the fact that I deleted the result with ID 2, so when loop over the table rows one of them is empty and that is way I am getting the Warning...

Comment: why not fix the code to remove warning?

Comment: I do not think I can because the data I have...

Comment: can you post the output of var_dump($rawResult['sections']); *after* you unserialize data ?

Comment: it is too long... but it is a multidimensional array. BTW Jeremy's answer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ensure the data is an array first or typecast it to an array.

Is array:

```
    if (is_array($rawResult['sections'])) {
        foreach ($rawResult['sections'] as $result_sections) {
            if ($result_sections['answers'][1]['mark'] == 'correct')
                $correct_answer++;
        }
    }
```

Typecast:

```
    foreach ( (array) $rawResult['sections'] as $result_sections) {
        if ($result_sections['answers'][1]['mark'] == 'correct')
            $correct_answer++;
    }
```